# how can i download code from git hub using command line

Tags: github, google-code

I know my question is obviously silly. I want to download and-engine for my game through Google Code. I found [Link](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/checkout) to download and-engine, but when i visited that link, I found this:

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/
```

I am also unable to download read only files from git-Hub "Get-Read-Only".

How can I download source code using command line?  Is there any software which i have to install on my Laptop to download it?

Comment: `git clone git://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine.git`

Comment: You need to have git installed on your machine to use it, although I should also point out that the repository you referenced is a mecurial repository, not git

Comment: Actually some time i have to download Git-Hub source. For git hub, which software ,i have to install?

Comment: You have to have git installed on your local machine to use git commands. I would highly advise looking over https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

Comment: I'm looking at a question that this was closed 4 years ago without a proper answer because some people thought it was too unlikely to help future visitors.  Thanks @RobertRouhani !!!  Boo random talonmies Eric rds Bohemian -- It was the first link from "download github command line" and GitHub is the top online code repository in Forbes' Cloud 100.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download following softwares to download projects like this

1 . The [SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) 
2.  The [Git](http://git-scm.com/downloads)